# problem creating lists inside custom environments

Tags: lists, document-classes

it's my first post here on LaTeX stackexchange, and it has to do with some problems I'm experiencing in using custom classes.

I'm trying to write my CV in LaTeX. I copied some code online to create a class file and the troublesome part has the following definition:

```
\newenvironment{eventlist}{%
\newcommand*\inskip{}
\renewcommand\item[3]{%
\inskip%
{\raggedleft\sc ##1\\[1pt]}
{##2}\\[2pt]
{\Large\it ##3}
\medskip
\renewcommand\inskip{\bigskip}}}
{\bigskip}
```

This should create a nice title for the sections *employment and education*.

Afterwards I declare in the main document, as an example:

```
\begin{eventlist}

\item{September 2013 -- To date}
 {Physics B.Sc. student}
 {ETH Z\"urich} 
  Here goes a description of what I did specifically, which is formatted in 
  'standard article font' and I'd love to have it in bullet point format.

  ...

\end{eventlist}
```

And everything works fine for now.

The trouble is that if I write stuff outside the `\item` brackets you see an example of above while still being inside the eventlist environment and try to create a list (by means of `\begin{itemize}`... `\end{itemize}`), the output is very bad, and not left-aligned at all.

However, I really need to have a bullet-point list in order to better convey ideas. Currently I am able to do this by using the • symbol, however you can understand why this is subpar (for one, it doesn't do indents after going onto the next line, which leads a messy-looking list).

Also, if you want to run this bit of code I recomment XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX as other compilers don't work (other compilers might for this part of the class file, but the whole thing only compiles with these two).

***To recap***: any ideas about how to create a nice-looking list while inside this environment?

Thank you very much for your help and support in advance!

Comment: Welcome! I notice you use `\"u`. It's best you use directly the `ü` character since it's supported, especially when you specify the utf-8 encoding

Comment: Thank you! In order to do that, I looked online and I need to write \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} instead of the usual babel, correct?

Comment: yes and no. You have to specify `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} ` instead of `\usepackage[yourPreviousEncoding]{inputenc}`; this has nothing to do with babel. Anyway it's recommended to use utf-8 encoding

Comment: The simplest thing would be to not change the item command, but define an `\eventitem` instead for your custom elements.

Comment: @AndrewSwann will I be able to use this *inside* the environment though? itemize should formally be the same as this custom element you're mentioning, and doesn't do the trick

Comment: Can you post a minimal complete document showing what you have so far, see [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) together with a mock up of the output you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose to do it with `enumitem` and a custom `description` environment. I replace  `\item`  with an `\event` command, which accepts three arguments and does the exact formatting.

```
\documentclass[12pt, british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{rowctr}
\newlist{eventlist}{description}{1}
\setlist[eventlist]{font=\normalfont, style=nextline, leftmargin=0pt}
\newcommand\event[3]{%
\item[\setcounter{rowctr}{0}%
\parbox{\linewidth}{{\hfill\textsc{#1}}\\\raggedright#2\\ \Large#3}]%
\leavevmode\vspace*{-\partopsep}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{eventlist}
  \event{September 2013 -- To date}
  {Physics B.Sc. student}
  {ETH Zürich}
  \begin{itemize}[wide, leftmargin =*]
    \item   Here goes a description of what I did specifically, which is formatted in
          \enquote{standard article font} and I'd love to have it in bullet point format.
    \item Some other description
  \end{itemize}
\end{eventlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! This was definitely what I needed. Apologies for not being very familiar with how class files work on LaTeX, unfortunately I was busy learning other pieces of code most of the time and I am not very proficient in this.